# Need a SQL query for this case

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following table

```
OrderNO   |    ParentNO
1         |        null
2         |        null
1         |       3
2         |       3
3         |       null
```

I need a SQL query which would retrieve the above table  data in the following order

```
OrderNO   |    ParentNO
    1         |        null
    2         |        null
    3         |       null 
    1         |       3
    2         |       3
```

The logic behind this view is first preference goes to the Order no with null , if a order no is available in parent no then it should displayed next to the respective order no.In the above sample - orderno1 with null comes in the first row then since orderno1 is not available in parentno then next orderno2 with  null parentno is displayed   since orderno2 is not available in parentno then next orderno3 with  null parentno is displayed then since  orderno3 is available in parentno the respective rows is displayed next 3.1
( 1         |       3) , next 3.2 (2         |       3)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `NULLS FIRST` as below

```
select OdrerNO, ParentNO
from tab
order by ParentNO NULLS FIRST, OdrerNO ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT OrderNo, ParentNo FROM
table
ORDER BY ParentNo ASC NULLS FIRST, OrderNo ASC
```

You need to specify `NULLS FIRST` on thd `ParentNo` column because by default `NULL` values go last in an ascending sort.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
Select * FROM TABLE
ORDER BY ParentNo, OrderNo
```

Nulls should come first if I remember rightly. So ordering it by parentNo will give the Nulls first, then order the orderNo. So will give the desired effect.

Comment: This won't give the desired effect since `NULL` values come _last_ in an ascending sort, which is the case for your query (`ASC` is the default order in Oracle).

Comment: Ah didnt see the oracle tag. Works fine in MS SQL server